# Ejabberd rooms invitation and join not working

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, multiuserchat, ejabberd-module

I've got an ejabberd (v14.07) self-hosted server, with both `mod_muc` and `mod_muc_admin` enabled.
I'm trying to create a conference room to make some users communicate through a common multi-chat.
Each client uses [AstraChat](http://www.astrachat.com) or [ChatSecure](https://chatsecure.org) apps.

Here there are the create room terminal commands I'm using to create a conference room.

```
# room creation
ejabberdctl create_room myroomname conference.$host $host

# sending invitations to users
ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation myroomname@conference.$host none "Join the multi-chat" user1
ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation myroomname@conference.$host none "Join the multi-chat" user2
ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation myroomname@conference.$host none "Join the multi-chat" user3

# setting room affiliations (is it required to the users to join the chat before?)
ejabberdctl set_room_affiliation myroomname conference.$host user1 owner
ejabberdctl set_room_affiliation myroomname conference.$host user2 member
ejabberdctl set_room_affiliation myroomname conference.$host user3 member
```

After this, I've got the room created (also visibile on the web interface of ejabberd).
Nevertheless, no notification or feedback is provided to the users.
Moreover, if I run:

```
ejabberdctl get_room_occupants myroomname conference.$host
```

the result is empty (also confirmed by ejabberd's web interface, showing 0 participants on the selected rooms).

It follows `ejabberd.yml` configuration snippet for `mod_muc`.

```
mod_muc: 
  ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
  access: muc_access
  access_create: muc_admin
  default_room_options:
    public: true
    public_list: true
    allow_change_subj: true
    allow_query_users: true
    allow_private_messages: true
    allow_user_invites: true
    members_by_default: true
    title: "New chatroom"
    anonymous: false
  access_admin: muc_admin
```

How can I get room join notification and users participation working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run below command for get affiliation because you have insert affiliation not occupants

```
ejabberdctl get_room_affiliations manish887 conference.192.168.32.18

@manish887 = room name

@conference.192.168.32.18 = muc_service
```